# HTML textarea show br

Tags: javascript, html

i have a textarea in HTML. In the textarea the blank line is is looks br.

I try to have the value of the some text. And posting with get. After i received with php. And i changed the value of the some text to variabled i get with get.

Like this :

```
a<br />b c
```

Code (post with javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}

        function menusec(secilen){

            var deger = secilen.options[secilen.selectedIndex].value;
            var urunadi = document.getElementById("okulueua").value;
            var urunfiyati = document.getElementById("okulueuf").value;
            var kargofiyati = document.getElementById("okuluekf").value;
            var aciklama = nl2br(document.getElementById("okulueat").value);

            alert(aciklama);

            window.location.href = "okulue.php?menu=" + deger + "&urunadi=" + urunadi + "&urunfiyati=" + urunfiyati + "&kargofiyati=" + kargofiyati + "&aciklama=" + aciklama;

        }

    </script>
```

Code (get with php) :

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['menu'])) {

        $secilendeger = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "menu");

        $urunadiget = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "urunadi");

        $urunfiyatiget = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "urunfiyati");

        $kargofiyatiget = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "kargofiyati");

        $aciklamaget = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "aciklama");

        echo($aciklamaget);

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function br2nl($content){

                $content = str_ireplace("<br /> ", "\n", $content);
                return $content;

            }

            function br2nl1($input){
    return preg_replace('/<br(\s+)?\/?>/i', "\n", $input);
}

            document.getElementById("menusecme1").style.width = "315px";

            document.getElementById("okulueua").value = "<?php echo($urunadiget); ?>";

            document.getElementById("okulueuf").value = "<?php echo($urunfiyatiget); ?>";

            document.getElementById("okuluekf").value = "<?php echo($kargofiyatiget); ?>";

            document.getElementById("okulueat").value = "<?php echo($aciklamaget); ?>";

            $('select[name^="ms1"] option[value="<?php echo($secilendeger); ?>"]').attr("selected","selected");

        </script>
```

Code (HTML) :

```
<input type="text" class="okulueuat" name="okulueua" id="okulueua">
<input type="text" class="okulueua2t" name="okulueua2" value="1000" readonly="yes">
<input type="text" class="okulueuft" name="okulueuf" id="okulueuf">
<input type="text" class="okuluekft" name="okuluekf" value="5" id="okuluekf">
<input type="submit" class="tamamb2" value="Tamam" name="submit">
<input type="button" class="iptalb2" value="İptal" onclick="location='okulul.php'">
<input type="file" name="okuluef[]" class="resimeklec" multiple="multiple">

<textarea id="okulueat" name="okuluea"></textarea>
```

How can i solve this problem?

I need your help.

Note : I don't have a good English. Pardon me. I hope you understand.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE -  there is far too little information here. Are you using an HTML textarea editor like tiniyMCE?

Comment: @mplungjan No. I don't use.I will change the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you have PHP and `<textarea><?php echo $someHTMLVar; ?></textarea>` then you need to unescape the variable

Comment: @mplungjan  but i change with javascript

Comment: How should we know. SHOW SOME CODE! There is not even a TAG with JavaScript. Please create a  [mcve]

Comment: Where is the HTML? What is okulueua  and is $urunadiget escaped?

Comment: `function br2nl($content){

                $content = str_ireplace("<br /> ", "\n", $content);
                return $content;

            }

            function br2nl1($input){
    return preg_replace('/<br(\s+)?\/?>/i', "\n", $input);
}` is not Javascript

Comment: @mplungjan Should i delete?

Comment: You are using PHP code in JavaScript that of course does not work. As I expected the PHP changes all \n to BR and then you do not change them back. You need to escape the \n or you will break the JavaScript. Then unescape them when you write to the textarea

Comment: @mplungjan i deleted this code.

Comment: @mplungjan result : ab c

Comment: Look in the  console and check if the wrap is hard on the text area

Comment: @mplungjan no problem in the console

Comment: Inspect the text area to see if there is a new line if yes add wrap=hard and if not fix your code

Comment: @mplungjan how can i convert br to a&#13;&#10;

Comment: Why would you? Just keep the \n but escape it on the server

Comment: @mplungjan when i change br to a&#13;&#10; the problem is solve

Comment: X13x10 is \r\n  so just escape the \n instead of converting to <br /> and converting back

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <textarea>a&#13;&#10;b c</textarea>
```

Comment: Gives the same result.

Comment: Result : a&#13;&#10;b c